# Calling JS file from html

Tags: javascript

My html file below trying to call roundChimney.js but just getting blank browser

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Chimney Volume</title>
<script src='roundChimney.js' ></script>
</head>
<body>`enter code here`
<script> alert(roundChimney(5,5));</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Code for roundChimney is

```
function roundChimney(radius, height) {
    var volume = radius * height;
    return Math.ceil(volume));  
   }
```

Comment: your .js file are on the same level, like your html?

Comment: try calling the script  just before close `</body>` tag

Comment: You have an extra `)` in the line `return Math.ceil(volume));`

Answer (score 0):

The function is not working because of your brackets, you should have two brackets instead of three return Math.ceil(volume)

```
function roundChimney(radius, height) {
  var volume = radius * height;
  return Math.ceil(volume);  
}
```

Try this now.

Answer (score -1):

You have to set the .js file path relative, for example:

```
<script src="../Script/roundChimney.js">
```

This way I assume your App fodler contains an index.html and a Script folder, what contains a roundChimney.js file.

Comment: why would you assume that the script was in a different place?

Comment: I don't, it's just an example to present how to link a script relative.